# Измерение высоты ViewGroup (ChipGroup)

Tags: android, view, android-ui

У меня есть `ChipGroup` виджет для отображения тэгов:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/tags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/desc"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:singleLine="false"
        app:chipSpacingVertical="@dimen/tag_padding"
        />
       ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Количество тэгов может быть любым, и их длина может быть любой, и я хочу проверить, когда высота `ChipGroup` виджета будет превышать две строки. 
Чтобы достичь этой цели, мне нужно узнать высоту `ChipGroup`.  Для этого я делаю следующее:

```
fun displayChips(tagsView: ChipGroup, tagNames: List<String>) {
    // вычисление фактической высоты дисплея
    val displayWidth = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
    Log.d(TAG, "displayWidth = $displayWidth")

    var chipHeight = 0
    var maxChipGroupHeight = 0
    val labelCount = tagNames.size

    for (i in 0 until labelCount) {
        val chip = Chip(tagsView.context)
        chip.text = tagNames[i]
        // ...
        chip.textSize = 14f
        chip.maxHeight = 22

        if (i == 0) {
            // измерение высоты одного тэга
            chip.measure(ChipGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ChipGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            chipHeight = chip.measuredHeight
            Log.d(TAG, "chipHeight = $chipHeight")
            // измерение высоты двух строк с тэгами (включая расстояние между строками)
            maxChipGroupHeight = 2 * chipHeight + resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tag_padding)
            Log.d(TAG, "maxChipGroupHeight = $maxChipGroupHeight")
        }
        tagsView.addView(chip)
        // вычисление высоты всего tagsView - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ :(
        tagsView.measure(displayWidth, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val tagsViewHeight = tagsView.measuredHeight
        Log.d(TAG, "i = $i, tagsViewHeight = $tagsViewHeight")

        if (tagsViewHeight > maxChipGroupHeight) {
            Log.d(TAG, "i = $i, tagsView height increased two lines")
            // ..
        }
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения этого кода я получаю следующие логи:

> displayWidth = 1080
>
> chipHeight = 96
>
> maxChipGroupHeight = 204
>
> i = 0, tagsViewHeight = 96
>
> i = 1, tagsViewHeight = 96
>
> i = 2, tagsViewHeight = 96
>
> i = 3, tagsViewHeight = 96
>
> i = 4, tagsViewHeight = 96
>
> i = 5, tagsViewHeight = 96

При том, что выглядят на экране тэги так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. проблема в том, что я получаю всё время одну и ту же высоту  `tagsView.measuredHeight` (равную 96), хотя она определённо должна меняться (ведь в итоге получилось три строки с тэгами).
Я пробовала также вызывать методы

```
tagsView.requestLayout()
tagsView.invalidate()
```

перед `tagsView.measure(...)`, однако это ничего не изменило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу немного попроще пример, чтобы показать в суть проблемы. Допустим есть некоторое приложение, в котором есть кнопка сверху и вертикальный LinearLayout под ней. При нажатии по кнопке в лайаут добаляется копия какого-то объекта, что меняет высоту лайаута. Ставим брейкпоинт в слушателе кнопки, запускаем в дебаге  и смотрим что происходит. Когда выполняется строчка `View v = new View(context);` у `v` высота и ширина будет 0, даже если это кнопка с текстом. Потом выполнится строка `layout.addView(v);` но и после нее высота v останется 0, как и высота лайаута. Потому что процессы, изменяющие размеры объектов - это методы mesure и requestLayout не выполняются мгновенно, а добавляют в Looper главного потока задачи на их исполнение. То есть сначала выполнится весь ваш код, и только через какое-то время изменится размер лайаута и лежащей в нем вьюшки

Примерно то же самое происходит у вас. Вы добавляете элементы и вызываете mesure. Но оно не выполняется сейчас, оно ставится в очередь, и до конца вашей функции не запустится точно. Что вам надо делать: используйте LayoutChangeListener. Вешаете его на ваш ChipLayout и при каждом изменении проверяете количество строк в нем. Да, кстати, количество строк наверняка можно получить от него просто числом, а не танцуя с высотой в пикселях =)

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развёрнутый ответ! Но, к сожалению, получить числом количество строк из СhipGroup нельзя(